# "Could not initialize class..." error in pom.xml with a new Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I wanted to learn how to develop RESTful APIs with JAX-RS and so started with an example covered in one of the YouTube videos. The video was created 5 -6 years ago and used Tomcat 7 and an older version of Eclipse. But I installed the recent versions of Tomcat (10.0.6) and Eclipse (jee-2021-03) and followed the tutorial.

I created a new maven project with the following archetype:
**Group Id**: org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes
**Artifact Id**: jersey-quickstart-webapp
**Version**: 3.0.2

I provided Group Id and Artifact Id for my project with default version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and clicked Finish.

Eclipse created the project with the following 2 errors:

1. **index.jsp**: "The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path"
2. **pom.xml**: "Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer" on the very first line.

I'd appreciate if someone can help me understand why I'm getting these errors and how to resolve them.

Here is my pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xyz.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>onlineshopping</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>onlineshopping</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>onlineshopping</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.0.2</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: It's a little hard to tell. Perhaps you should start with a different tutorial: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jersey-example/ .

Comment: Thanks David for recommending another tutorial. But I wanted to complete my tutorials as I had watched a few videos of the same guy covering theory and I liked his series. But it has been frustrating to see this error. Could you please suggest a few things that I can try, or someone on the board who could be of help?

Answer (score 1):

for first problem:

1. right click on your project
2. click Properties
3. click Targeted Runtimes
4. tick mark Apache Tomcat v10.0
5. click Apply and Close

for second problem:
add the following plugin inside the pom.xml file inside build -> plugins

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

your pom.xml file should be like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xyz.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>onlineshopping</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>onlineshopping</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>onlineshopping</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.0.2</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Hope this will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

For 1/ index.jsp
add the following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

for 2/ pom.xml
add the following property at the end of eclipse.ini and restart eclipse

```
--illegal-access=permit
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Could not initialize class `org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer`

   This message is not an error it is a bug of eclipse new version so you need to take older version or need to wait for fixing this bug.
2. For fixing this you can use below code in pom.XML file try this it will fix error message -:

   ```
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
   ```